# Pandas - Avoid boolean result when using groupby()

Tags: python, pandas, groupby

I have this script:

```
    sectors = df.groupby(['company_sector']).mean()['investment_in_millions']
```

Output:

[image]

I wanted to keep the same groupy() but having a result in "investment_in_millions" column filtered as mean > 10 or another value.

If apply this:

```
     sectors = df.groupby(['company_sector']).mean()['investment_in_millions']>10
```

I keep the groupby() but it returns a boolean into the investment column.

If I use:

```
     filtered = df[df['investment_in_millions']>10]
```

I get the filtered values mean>10 but the groupby() is not there anymore and I get all the other columns in the excel.

How can I get the groupby() together with the mean>10 without getting a boolean result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First filter your results:

```py
filtered_df = df[df['investment_in_millions']>10]
```

And then group it by `company_sector`

```py
import numpy as np 

sectors = filtered_df.groupby(['company_sector']).agg({"investment_in_millions":np.mean})
```

You can do it in one line:

```
sectors = df[df['investment_in_millions']>10].groupby(['company_sector']).agg({"investment_in_millions":np.mean})
```

Comment: thank you! Can I ask you why .agg needs a dictionary?

Comment: Sure!, this is quite useful since you can specify inside the dictionary, more than one column and apply them virtually any aggregate function

Comment: ok, I see. Thanks again!